# "No Driver Found" on Windows 7 x64 with Logitech MK300

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, logitech-mouse, logitech-keyboard

I bought a Logitech MK300 keyboard/mouse, and I'm trying to use them on a 64-bit Windows 7 PC.

When I connect the USB-receiver, Windows is trying to install it but gives me the error message: "no driver found". I tried to download SetPoint 4.80, but that didn't help.

I have rebooted the computer several times, tried different USB ports, and have also tried many different mice from Logitech. None of this works.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can fix my problem?

Answer (score 2):

1. Remove the USB receiver from your computer & uninstall whatever SetPoint software you had installed prior.
2. Go [here](http://www.logitech.com/index.cfm/433/5755&cl=nz,en?bit=&osid=14) and select "SetPoint 64-bit" and download the software.
3. Once the software is done downloading, install it.
4. Once the software is finished installing, insert the USB receiver into a known-working USB port on your computer.
5. It should work from there, but you might need to sync the mouse to the computer (usually with a little red button on both the receiver and the mouse).